# Fill column values based on time of day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data with timestamps, I want to resample and back fill column rows with the logged value starting from a specified time until the logged time.

Here is what the data looks like

```
df
timestamp              col1  
2020-10-10 09:21:00     20     
2020-10-11 10:42:00     30          
..
```

I want to resample it to 10-minute intervals, and fill col1 values starting from 06:00:00 with the logged value until the log time, to look like this:

```
df
timestamp              col1       
2020-10-10 06:00:00     20
2020-10-10 06:10:00     20
2020-10-10 06:20:00     20
...
2020-10-10 09:20:00     20
2020-10-10 09:30:00     NaN
2020-10-10 09:40:00     NaN
...
2020-10-11 06:00:00     30
2020-10-11 06:10:00     30
..
2020-10-11 10:40:00     30
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) your starting point, and [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), then [`groupby.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html) per day:

```
out = (
 pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [df['timestamp'].min().normalize()+pd.Timedelta('06:00:00')]}), df])
   .resample('10min', on='timestamp').mean().reset_index()
)
out.groupby(out['timestamp'].dt.normalize()).bfill()
```

Output:

```
              timestamp  col1
0   2020-10-10 06:00:00  20.0
1   2020-10-10 06:10:00  20.0
2   2020-10-10 06:20:00  20.0
3   2020-10-10 06:30:00  20.0
4   2020-10-10 06:40:00  20.0
..                  ...   ...
18  2020-10-10 09:00:00  20.0
19  2020-10-10 09:10:00  20.0
20  2020-10-10 09:20:00  20.0
21  2020-10-10 09:30:00   NaN
22  2020-10-10 09:40:00   NaN
23  2020-10-10 09:50:00   NaN
..                  ...   ...
168 2020-10-11 10:00:00  30.0
169 2020-10-11 10:10:00  30.0
170 2020-10-11 10:20:00  30.0
171 2020-10-11 10:30:00  30.0
172 2020-10-11 10:40:00  30.0
```